# Cloning Select SelectedIndex

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to merge two forms together so I can submit both data in one POST. I don't want to do an AJAX call otherwise I would use serialization. I'm using the following JQuery to merge the forms...

```
$('#formA :input').clone().hide().appendTo('#formB');
```

However, the selected indexes of my select inputs aren't copied over and are simply set to the first option. I'm not very proficient in JQuery so I don't know how I would go about copying the selected value over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var indexes = [];

$('form select').each(function(k,v) {
   indexes.push ($(this).find('option').filter(':selected').index())
});


$('form#two')
    .append($('form#one :input').clone())        
    .find('select')
    .each(function(k,v) {
        $(this).find('option').eq(indexes[k]).attr('selected','selected')            
    })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HbK2c/

Comment: This isn't cloning. This is simply moving the inputs from one form to another. Both forms have to remain intact for the user to see.

Comment: Thanks. That seems to work fine however I think this will only work for one select input. I have two selects on my form and this will only copy the first select it finds.

Comment: Then you'll need a little loop logic. I updated the answer with new code.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your full code, to transfer the selected index would be something like...

```
$("#formB :input).find(':selected').val($('#formA :input').find(':selected').val());
```

Though there are far better ways of doing it.  If the user isn't going to interact with that drop down menu on #formB, you can just add a  field instead.